# echo from different php page into div

Tags: php, javascript

I just created an function that is supposed to read my echo from an PHP file. I think the function is working, but seems to be something with my php file.

this is my function

```
function CallProverb(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
  url: "Example_RSS_Feed.php",
  data: paramas,
    success: function(responseText)
    {
    document.getElementById("ContentHolder").innerHTML = responseText;
    }
  }
);
}
```

And my PHP file, Its an rss feed with an array.

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");  


        $rssFeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        $rssFeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
        $rssFeed .= '<channel>';
        $rssFeed .= '<title>Example RSS feed</title>';
        $rssFeed .= '<link>http://localhost/Example_RSS_Feed.php</link>';
        $rssFeed .= '<description>This is an example RSS feed called for at ' . date("l n F") . '</description>';
        $rssFeed .= '<language>sv</language>';
        $rssFeed .= '<copyright>Created 2010 by Mikael Hasselmalm</copyright>';

        $rssFeed .= '<item>';
        $rssFeed .= '<title>Example feed</title>';
        $rssFeed .= '<description>';

        $rssFeed .= 'Exempel på ett RSS-flöde anropat ' . date("l n F");

        $rssFeed .= '</description>';
        $rssFeed .= '<link>LINK</link>';
        $rssFeed .= '<pubDate>' . date("l n F") . '</pubDate>';
        $rssFeed .= '</item>';

        $rssFeed .= '</channel>';
        $rssFeed .= '</rss>';

        $counter = array(1 => 'one.', ' two ', 'three ',);
       echo $counter[2];
```

so its supposed to output two in my contentholder, but I cant =/

Comment: What is the point in building that RSS string if you never echo it? The sum total of what your PHP script does is `echo ' two ';`, none of the other work it does has any effect on anything whatsoever.

Comment: `so its supposed to output two in my contentholder` - what does it do instead? `but I cant` - I can't either. Understand your question, that is...

Comment: What I mean is that nothing prints out in my div tag.

Comment: Are you sure `CallProverb`function is called? Is ajax firing?

Comment: What happens if you `alert(responseText)`? Are you sure the `success` call back is firing? What happens if you load the AJAX url in a browser?

Comment: Yes Im sure its working, have another function that calls from an other php file, that works perfect. But this one does not =/.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the jQuery files?

You can try to remove the HEAD information from your PHP and try.

Remove this line:

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
```

The PHP header might be creating a problem with the output.